# How to add css in HTML title

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a datatable for my data population.I am using Title for the header tooltip.But can i use css along with it?
Like i tried

```
#mainTable title {  
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size : 30px;
  color:red;
}
```

and i want to use css in table header inside th

```
 var createTable = '<table id="mainTable" class="display"><thead><tr><th title="Starting date of the period in which the activity occurred.">Period Starting</th><th title=Intelligence(Milestone)>Intelligence</th><th title=Engaged(Milestone)>Engaged</th><th>Qualification</th><th>Internal Submission</th><th>Present</th><th>Interviewed</th><th>Support</th><th>Placement</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
```

Can i achieve anyhow?

Comment: You can't style the `title` attribute tooltip

Comment: You can't style the built-in tooltips that show via the `title` attribute. Their appearance is decided by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

short answer: you can't.

long answer:  you could create your own tooltip popup that you have css control over using javascript.  you could write your own, or use one of many available plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    .ui-tooltip-content {  
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size : 30px;
      color:red;
    }
```

Assuming I've read the question right?

Comment: @ Matthew not working

Comment: Updated the answer, if you want to give it a try.

Comment: tried your code not working..what is .ui-tooltip-content??